# Is it possible to Rename the output key in Mongo's MapReduce Result?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to perform an Inline mapreduce operation using pyMongo.

The code looks like this:

```
import pymongo
from bson.code import Code

con = pymongo.MongoClient()

map_func = Code("""
                function() {
                    var all = this.members.concat(this.admins)
                    var group_id = this._id
                    all.forEach(function(_id) {
                        emit(_id, [group_id])
                    })
                }
                """)

reduce_func = Code("""
                   function(key, values) {
                        var ob = {};
                        ob[key] = [];
                        for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
                            ob[key].push(values[i][0])
                        }
                        return ob
                   }
                   """)

finalize_func = Code("""
                     function(key, value) {
                        if (typeof(value.push) == "function") {
                            return value
                        } else {
                            return value[key]
                        }
                     }
                     """)

result = con.test.group.inline_map_reduce(
    map_func,
    reduce_func,
    finalize=finalize_func)

import pprint; pprint.pprint(result)
```

Output for this operation is:

```
 [{u'_id': u'135348133252952338363702',
  u'value': [u'135457069105859781018098',
             u'135661481520484615218098',
             u'135391961249458761918098',
             u'135758863859275369318098',
             u'135156779012512657918098',
             u'135285081801846289218098',
             u'136040996346306049718098',
             u'136237587535011048218098',
             u'136862399436556328318098']},
 {u'_id': u'136068596781820946163702',
  u'value': [u'136068597966313224518098',
             u'135156779012512657918098',
             u'136415311739865096818098']}]
```

Is there any hook/operator by which I can rename the output field to any custom string example "group_id" instead of "values" ?

I have read Mongo's MapReduce documentation, but did not find any tip on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the reduced values are always in a field named `value`.

Comment: Thanks. Any chance that such a feature might be considered anytime soon ?

Comment: We've discussed a feature to give you more control over mapreduce output, you can vote for it here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2517. As with any feature, we have to balance its usefulness against the complexity it would add.

Answer (score 2):

Using the MapReduce `finalize` hook described [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/#mapreduce-finalize-mtd), I reformatted my output to the field names I wanted:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
  mapFunction(),
  reduceFunction(),
  {
    query: {params},
    finalize: function(key, reduced_value) {
      return {
        my_field: key,
        my_value: reduced_value
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: This is close to requested operation, but the returned object is still under a value field